# Is a JavaScript array order guaranteed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, post

Assuming a JavaScript array is posted in a form (using ajax/JQuery)
is the order in the array guaranteed?

Valid question from @Quentin
"Define 'posted in a form'"

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: { foo: [{ name: "one" }, { name: "two" }] },
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Expanding on the question (because of the above),
Is the array guaranteed to preserve the order on the server side?

Comment: Arrays are ordered collections.

Comment: Why would you assume that array order would not be preserved? As far as I know, only object property order is not guaranteed.

Comment: i have encountered situations where the order was not preserved (in other languages), therefore the question.

Comment: Which languages and how to reproduce this?

Comment: see http://blog.caplin.com/2012/01/13/javascript-is-hard-part-1-you-cant-trust-arrays/

Comment: my opinion: The "trust" issue with that blog post is a person not understanding arrays.

Comment: Feel free to down-vote me for a legitimate question without explaining....

Comment: @epascarello - Thats why i turned to the wisdom of the masses.

Comment: If arrays did not have guaranteed order we would have a problem. Object keys on the other hand do not have guaranteed order.

Comment: Thanks for the comments/answers.

Comment: Read the spec http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4

Comment: Define "posted in a form". Once you hit HTML (or HTTP) then you usually aren't dealing with JavaScript any more (but possibly some serialization).

Comment: @Quentin - please see edited question

Comment: Right, once you "post" it. It's not longer a javascript array but some sort of representation for it, which can or not be parsed in an orderly fashion.

Comment: In this particular example, jQuery serializes your array as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the order isn't really guaranteed unless the server enforces it. JSON would be a much better alternative, as it supports ordered collections.

Comment: @MinusFour -What? pretty sure that is json.

Comment: jQuery serialize objects on `data` with `jQuery.param` and not `JSON.stringify`. You'll need to serialize the object manually with `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @MinusFour - are you recommending to send the json back as a string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101436/discussion-between-minusfour-and-dementic).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can always refer to the ECMAScript standard when in doubts: [Array Exotic Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-exotic-objects)

Array is a special kind of object in the language that have additional semantic on how length property is handled respect to the properties that are integers from 0 to 2^32. In javascript an array can be sparse if there are missing values in the range of 0 to the length property excluded. Various array methods take this in consideration, for example [forEach](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) ignore missing values

What is a missing value?

The language tries to make arrays act as much as possible as to normal objects: you can add any property to it and even have objects that inherit from an array.

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"];
fruits.preferred = "Apple";
```

This kind of code don't pose any problem, but if you start to write:

```
fruits[100] = "Strawberry";
for(let i = 0; i < fruits.length; ++i) {
...
}
```

100 is a property name in the range of [0, 2^32) so is an array element but at this point what fruits.length should be? It must be 101, otherwise the for loop will never get "Strawberry".

But at this point you have to accept that there is a range of element [2, 99] that were never defined: these are missing values.

Vice versa the same must be true when you modify the length property

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"];
fruits.length = 0;
```

Now a for loop will never get any element of the array: this is equivalent to emptying the fruits array.

It's also possible to increment the length, with the result of having missing values

So yes arrays are ordered as you can iterate all its elements in increasing order, but keep in mind that there can be missing values

Comment: Can you expand on `Missing Values` ?

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to the blog post i commented with, but pretty sure others will find this helpfull.

Comment: Does `forEach` iterate in increasing order?