# $.each doesn't respect the order of an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to order a multidimensional array in PHP and then pass it to my javascript file to display it. I use the function `$.map` and `$.each` to display the data. The problem is that the JS reorder the array according to the id. eg if I have an array like this.

```
$array = array(1 => array('name' => 'A','last' => 'B'), 
               5 => array('name' => 'C','last' => 'D'),
               2 => array('name' => 'K','last' => 'Z'));
```

Javascript will sort it this way

```
    array = {1:{name:'A',last:'B'},2:{name:'C',last:'D'},5:{name:'K',last:'Z'}}
```

I'm using **uasort** to sort my array according to the name :

```
public function specialNameComparison($firstElmnt,$secondElmnt){
    if ($firstElmnt['name'] == $secondElmnt['name']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($firstElmnt['name'] < $secondElmnt['name']) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($users,array($this,'specialNameComparison'));
echo json_encode($users);
die();
```

And in javascript as I said i'am using `$.each` (I've tried `$.map` to) to simply display the data

```
$.each(json, function(key,value) {
   console.log(value.name);
 });
```

Why Javascript is doing this !?

Comment: You do not have an array. That is an object if it has { and }

Comment: To expand on what epscarello said, what you have is an _object_, not an _array_. There is no guarantee to the ordering of keys on an object.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955787/is-a-javascript-array-order-guaranteed

Comment: PHP associative arrays become objects in javascript.  Javascript does not have the concept of an associative array, natively.

Comment: is there any proper way to achieve what I want to do ?

Comment: Convert it to be a real array, and then order will be guaranteed.

Comment: `json_encode(array_values($users))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As above commenters have pointed out you are creating an object not an array in JS there are no associative arrays and denoting your indices puts you into the context of an 'array like object'. if you need those keys I would advise something like:

```
$array = [
  [ 'key' => 1, 'name' => 'A','last' => 'B' ], 
  [ 'key' => 5, 'name' => 'C','last' => 'D' ],
  [ 'key' => 2, 'name' => 'K','last' => 'Z' ],
];
```

which when json encoded will output:

```
[
  { "key": 1, "name": "A","last": "B" }, 
  { "key": 5, "name": "C","last": "D" },
  { "key": 2, "name": "K","last": "Z" },
]
```

then your js can be:

```js
const arr =  [
  { key: 1, name: 'A',last: 'B' }, 
  { key: 5, name: 'C',last: 'D' },
  { key: 2, name: 'K',last: 'Z' },
];

arr.forEach(({key, name, last }) => console.log(`key: ${key} - ${name} ${last}`))
```