# What is the order of execution of the same-type hooks in fastify?

Tags: fastify

In Fastify.js you have at least to ways to register hooks: globally (via `fastify.addHook()`) or as a property inside the route declaration. In the example below I'm trying to use fastfy-multer to handle file uploading but the maximum amount of files must be limited by a setting associated with a "room". As the app has many rooms, most of the requests contain a reference to a room, and every time the request is being augmented with room settings by the preHandler hook.

```
import fastify from 'fastify'
import multer from 'fastify-multer'

const server = fastify()
server.register(multer.contentParser)

// For all requests containing the room ID, fetch the room options from the database
fastify.addHook('preHandler', async (request, reply) => {
    if (request.body.roomID) {
        const roomOptions = await getRoomOptions(request.body.roomID)
        if (roomOptions) {
            reuqest.body.room = roomOptions
        }
        else {
            // handle an error if the room doesn't exist
        }
    }
})

server.post('/post', {
    // Limit the maximum amount of files to be uploaded based on room options
    preHandler: upload.array(files, request.body.room.maxFiles)
})
```

In order for this setup to work, the global hook must always be executed before the file upload hook. How can I guarantee that?

Comment: `How can I guarantee that?` The framework does it

Answer (score 7):

Summary: As [@Manuel Spigolon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3309466/manuel-spigolon) said:

> How can I guarantee that? The framework does it

Now we can take Manuel's word for it (**SPOILER ALERT**: they are absolutely correct), or we can prove how this works by looking in the [source code](https://github.com/fastify/fastify) on GitHub.

The first thing to keep in mind is that arrays in JavaScript are remain ordered by the way objects are pushed into them, but don’t take my word for it. That is all explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955787/is-a-javascript-array-order-guaranteed) if you want to dive a little deeper into the evidence. If that was not true, everything below doesn't matter and you could just stop reading now.

#### How `addHook` works

Now that we have established that arrays maintain their order, let look at how the `addHook` code is executed. We can start by looking at the default export of fastify in the [`fastify.js`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/fastify.js#L204) file located in the root directory. In this object if scoll down you'll see the [`addHook`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/fastify.js#L278) property defined. When we look into the [`addHook` function implementation](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/fastify.js#L560-L596) we can see that in that add hook call we are calling [`this[kHooks].add`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/fastify.js#L593).

When we go back to see what the `kHooks` property is we see that it is a [`new Hooks()`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/fastify.js#L219). When we go to take a look at the [`add`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/lib/hooks.js#L58-L61) method on the `Hooks` object, we can see that it just validates the hook that is being add and then [`push`es] it to the [array](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/lib/hooks.js#L35-L48) property on the `Hooks` object with the matching hook name. This shows that hooks will always be in the order which add was called for them.

#### How `fastify.route` adds hooks

I hope you're following to this point because that only proves the order of the `addHook` calls in the respective `array` on the `Hooks` object. The next question is how these interact with the calls of [`fastify.(get | post | route | ...)`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/fastify.js#L239-L269) functions. We can walk through the [`fastify.get`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/fastify.js#L243-L245) function, but they are all pretty much the same (you can do the same exercise with any of them). Looking at the `get` function, we see that the implementation is just calling the [`router.prepareRoute`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/fastify.js#L244) function. When you look into the [`prepareRoute` implementation](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/lib/route.js#L115-L143), you see that this function returns a call to the [`route`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/lib/route.js#L153-L356) function. In the route function there is a [section where the hooks are set up](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/lib/route.js#L297-L302). It looks like this:

```
for (const hook of lifecycleHooks) {
  const toSet = this[kHooks][hook]
    .concat(opts[hook] || [])
    .map(h => h.bind(this))
  context[hook] = toSet.length ? toSet : null
}
```

What this does is go through every lifecycle hook and turn it into a set of all the hooks from the Fastify instance (`this`) and the hooks in the options (`opts[hook]`) for that given hook and binds them to the fastify instance (`this`). This shows that the hooks in the options for the routes are always added after the `addHook` handlers.

#### How Fastify executes hooks

This is not everything we need though. Now we know the order in which the hooks are stored. But how exactly are they executed? For that we can look at the [`hookRunner`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/lib/hooks.js#L163-L197) function in the hooks.js file. We see this function acts as a sort of recursive loop that continues running as long as the handlers do not error. It first creates a variable [`i`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/lib/hooks.js#L164) to keep track of the handler function it is currently on and then tries to [execute](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/lib/hooks.js#L174) it and increments the function tracker (`i`).

If the handler [fails (`handleReject`)](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/lib/hooks.js#L180), it [runs a callback function](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/lib/hooks.js#L193) and does not call the [`next`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/lib/hooks.js#L182) function to continue. If the handler [succeeds (`handleResolve`)](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/lib/hooks.js#L180), it just [runs the `next` function](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/aa43e2de2cac18d7654c6a88e5437f8b0854872e/lib/hooks.js#L185) to try the same process on the following handler (`functions[i++]`) in the functions set.

#### Why does this matter

This proves that the hook handlers are called in the order that they were pushed into the ordered collection. *In other words*:

> How can I guarantee that? The framework does it